# Unable to put correct status into another column upon comparing previous two

Tags: dataframe, python-3.7, openpyxl, data-analysis, xlrd

I am trying to run the following snippet but I am not getting desired output. Actually, I am trying to compare two cells in an excel file and print True/False into 'Status' column. Please refer to snippet of code and output below. Also refer to excel output. HELP NEEDED.

```
for i in range(sheet.max_row + 1):
    for j in range(1, sheet.max_column):
        print(i)
        print(j)
        if i == j:
            if sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value == sheet.cell(row=i, column=j + 1).value:
                print('inside true case')
                sheet.cell(row=i, column= sheet.max_column).value = 'True'
            else:
                print('inside false case')
                sheet.cell(row=i, column=sheet.max_column).value = 'False'
        print('----')


    C:\Users\Sambhav\PycharmProjects\ParallelRunUtility\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Sambhav/PycharmProjects/ParallelRunUtility/main.py
(10, 1)
(17, 1)
              Unit_Price_x  Unit_Price_y Status
PolicyNumber                                   
12345               231.49        569.72       
45678               208.93        208.93       
0
1
----
0
2
----
0
3
----
1
1
inside false case
----
1
2
----
1
3
----
2
1
----
2
2
inside false case
----
2
3
----
3
1
----
3
2
----
3
3
inside false case
----

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcd4K.png)